# $a_1 = 2, a_{n+1} = 2a^2_n+1, a_n = ?$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I got this problem from my friend. I have been doing it for hours.

$a_1 = 2$

$a_{n+1} = 2a^2_n+1$

$a_n = ?$

Could you please tell me how to solve this? Thanks!

BTW: I failed to solve it by using Mathematica `RSolve[{a[1] == 2, a[n + 1] == 2 a[n]^2 + 1}, a[n], n]`

Comment: @aziiri Well, the problem occurred when we new university students chatting online. Maybe he's out of curiosity. I tried to solve it in Mathematica, but it outputted what I inputed (, which meant it failed to solve the problem?)

Comment: I was mistaken, this not a duplicate. This sequence grows rapidly $>2^{2^n}$.

Comment: I think something very close or identical to this was asked and answered here roughly a week ago.

Comment: Try trig substitution.

Comment: I'm not sure you'll be able to get a general solution for this (nonlinear!) recursion. But numerically it does seem to have well-defined asymptotic behavior: $\log_2(a_n) \approx  1.4427 \times 2^n$ as $n\to\infty$, consistent with @aziiri's comment above.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, possibly just a typo here, closed form solution with minus sign: $a_1 = 2, \; \; a_{n+1} = 2 a_n^2 - 1$

Comment: Yes, for that one use double "angle" formula, hyperbolic cosine or plain cosine, depending on size of the first erm.

Comment: I'm too tired to do it myself, but try substituting $t_n=\cosh^{-1}(a_n)$.

Answer (score 3):

Take $b_n = 2 a_n,$ this becomes
$$  b_{n+1} = b_n^2 + 2, \; \; b_1 = 4.  $$
This is a well-known problem, the general heading is Lucas-Lehmer sequences. The best that can be done is that there is a real number $\theta > 1$ such that
$$ b_n \approx \theta^{\left( 2^n \right)},$$ where the really bad news is that you can only get estimates of $\theta$ by using more and more terms.

If your problem had a minus sign instead, then there would be a closed form solution!  Given
$$  x_{n+1} = x_n^2 - 2, \; \; \; x_0 > 2,  $$
find the constants $A > B > 0$ such that $$ AB = 1, \; \;  A+B = x_0.  $$
Then
$$  x_n = A^{\left( 2^n \right)} + B^{\left( 2^n \right)}  $$

So, my suspicion is that there was a lapse in communication, and the problem was originally $$\color{blue}{ a_1 = 2, \; \; a_{n+1} = 2 a_n^2 - 1.}   $$

Comment: You are more than probably right. Otherwise, there was no reason not to start with $a_1=1$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, as Will Jagy suspected, that the problem is $${ a_1 = 2, \; \; a_{n+1} = 2 a_n^2 - 1}$$ using a CAS I obtained, after some manipulations and simplifications, the surprizing form $$a_n=\cosh\Big(2^{n-1}\log(2+\sqrt 3)\Big)$$ or $$a_n=\frac{1}{2} \left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)^{-2^{n-1}}
   \left(1+\left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)^{2^n}\right)$$

Comment: I couldn't quite remember, but worked it out and then looked it up to confirm, $\cosh 2x = 2 \cosh^2 x - 1,$ which seems the most likely reason for having the $2 a_n^2.$ Also explains the second or third comment (above) by Andre Nicolas.

Comment: @WillJagy. I arrive to the same as you later. Thanks